# Which is faster: specifying a relative or absolute URL to a PHP script in an img tag?

Tags: php, html, image

I have two php scripts in the same directory-`a.php` and `b.php` . b.php creates an images and displays it.(Example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php)).

`a.php`

```
<html>
<body>

<img src=<?php echo "b.php";?> alt="image"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Both `<?php echo "b.php";?>` and `<?php echo "http://localhost/b.php";?>` work. But I want to know which will display the image faster? Or both will be the same?

Comment: Why use PHP to output a static value?

Comment: @Phoenix There are a number of reasons - development vs production servers, retrieving remote content, etc. Just because the filename of the script doesn't change, that doesn't mean the siteroot won't change.

Comment: @Matt I meant why use PHP to echo the static string "b.php".

Comment: @Phoenix just acting as devil's advocate I'd say it's just a bad example.

Comment: @Phoenix @Matt, that said, I'm pretty sure the example wouldn't even work with `<?php echo "http://localhost/b.php";?>` as there's no quotes surrounding the URL in his `src` property. I may, however, be wrong in this statement (as OP clearly states that it works)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They should both be the same, as your browser would make a new request for the picture anyway, however I'd suggest you to *always* use `b.php`, or another kind of relative path instead of the full (absoloute) path (UNLESS the picture is on another server, of course).

Answer (score 1):

This is irrelevant. The PHP script will execute in a fraction of a second and the browser needs to process the HTML. The browser will also process this in a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same. The difference is just the relative or absolute path.